# how to implement user keyguard Manager class as some of methods are deprecated

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an application which can disable the key-guard. getting lots of errors.
.. please help me to sort out :
 -> whether I have to implement as activity or action
 -> settings of android.manifest file if different.